# Difference between reading in vs declaring string python

Tags: python, string, pyserial

What is the difference (if any) between declaring a string in python vs reading in their value?

I have a piece of my code code which looks like:

```
file = open('comport.txt','r')

for line in file:
    if "comport" in line:
        comport = line[9:]
```

and the text file just looks like:

```
comport= COM1
```

When I try to open up a serial port, I do:

```
ser = serial.Serial(comport,baudrate=115200)
```

which doesn't work (bunch of errors), but this works:

```
comport = 'COM1'
ser = serial.Serial(comport,baudrate=115200)
```

I've tried putting the quotes in the text file and that didn't work either, i'm pretty sure i'm splitting my line correctly too because when I try printing it, it prints `COM1`

Comment: Probably there is still a `\n` after `COM1`

Comment: I think you meant `for line in file.readlines():`  Also, you should refrain from using `file` as a variable name, it's a python built-in.

Comment: @Will: no, file objects are iterable producing lines as needed using a buffer, this is memory efficient), using `file.readlines()` instead reads all lines into memory first, and is **not a good idea**. `file` is the name of the type in Python 2, in Python 3 that name is gone; it is not *that* bad to mask it as it is rarely used. Still, it is preferable to name it something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably there is still a linebreak `\n` after `"COM1"`. Try this:

```
    comport = line[9:].strip()
```

or this:

```
    comport = line.split("=")[1].strip()
```

Also, you should use `with` to open *and close* the file, and don't use `file` as a variable name.

```
with open('comport.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
```